# Why doesn't my player stick to my moving platform?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For some reason, even after following a tutorial, my player just slides off. Here is my code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.transform.parent = this.transform;
            Debug.Log("Player");
        }
    }



    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            collision.transform.parent = null;
        }
    }

}
```

I can see that the platform detects and designates the player as a child, but for some reason, it doesn't seem to affect him at all. Btw I am aware that there are multiple people that have already asked this question but nothing works for me.

Comment: are you sure that code is being executed, as a trigger it would mean likely falling through said platform.. would it not be a collider?

Comment: Probably because it still has an active `Rigibody` and those move in world space .. no matter the hierarchy => never parent `Rigidbody` but rather use a [Joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html) or where these don't really apply for your situation you might need to rather calculate the absolute world space forces yourself

Answer (score 0):

I am also new in unity.
Set is Trigger to off on both Player and Platform.